# Explosion event of IRAS 05506+2414?

Tags: explosion

From NASA's September 23, 2022 [Hubble Unveils an Astronomical Explosion](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/goddard/2022/hubble-unveils-an-astronomical-explosion):

> A shroud of thick gas and dust surrounds a bright young star in this image from the NASA/ESA Hubble Space Telescope. Hubble’s Wide Field Camera 3 inspected a young stellar object, over 9,000 light-years away in the constellation Taurus, to help astronomers understand the earliest stages in the lives of massive stars. This object – which is known to astronomers as IRAS 05506+2414 – may be an example of an explosive event caused by the disruption of a massive young star system.

What "disruption" really happened? Assuming it exploded, why and how? The article unfortunately provides no other details of what happened.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2008ApJ...680..483S/abstract
 And 
https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017ApJ...850..158S/abstract